# Can you use xbox360 controller and chat pad / messenger pad as a mouse and keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, xbox360, controller

Can you use xbox360 controller and chat pad / messenger pad as a mouse and keyboard?

I know you can use xbox360 controller in games but I would like to use as an alternative for mouse and keyboard. Can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried it? Given that the controller "just works" the keyboard might too.

Comment: I have tried the Xbox controller. But it doesn't "just work" and I have installed the driver for te wireless Xbox adapter.

Comment: It been a while since In tried the wired controller so there could have been a driver to install - but it installed automatically - which was my point. If you try the controller + messenger pad it might be recognised and install the necessary drivers.

Comment: Nope no result. It doesnt even work when Im playing a game. If it makes im on Window 8 preview version.